# Is MMAP storage engine from mongo3 backwards compatible with mongo 2.x

Tags: mongodb

We are seeing some performance issues after moving to mongodb 3.0 from 2.6, I am hopeful a rebuild of the dataset using the mmap storage engine will fix the problem. Has the underlying implementation of MMAP changed between versions which would either cause a performance issue or mean we can not roll back if required?

Comment: in short it is fully backwards compat

Comment: thanks, is there a long answer?

Comment: Not really, all I can really add is that the last breaking change was when the new style indexes was released in 1.8 which would have meant a reimport of your data.